# how to read the data from a text file stored in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, text-files

I have a text file stored in my sql DB. in that .txt file I have certain numbers like:

```
99435
87889
33455
33555
34556
```

How to get the count of these numbers from the txtfile stored in the database?  Also to read the file and fetch the number one by one in a string?

I am using asp.net (C#)

Comment: You have a 'file' stored in a Database? As a Blob? Please give some details.

Comment: Where you say "sql DB" do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: This rather smells of bad database design. It sounds like you should be storing each row of the text file in it's own row with a foreign key back to the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henk says, we need some more details about how the file/data is stored, but after you've got the file into memory as a string all you need to do is something similar to:

```
string[] array = data.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of numbers: {0}", array.Length));  
foreach(string str in array)  
{  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);  
}
```